# export functional component with injectIntl without using default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Now I have two components, List and Item. Since Item is only used in List, I want to put them in a single JSX file. However, the item has to be wrapped with `injectIntl` to enable the functionality of the i18n string.

I found that I cannot export Item without adding `default`, while List is exported by default already and the only way I can do is to import Item from another file or pass the translated string from List to Item.

I wonder why can't I do with the following code and is there any better practice I can follow while using `injectIntl` in functional components?

```js
// for simplicity imports are omitted
// Item and List are written in the same file (List.jsx)

const Item = ({content, intl}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{intl.formatMessage(content.i18nkey)}</h1>
      <img src={content.imgURL} />
    </>
  )
}

export injectIntl(Item); // this line is reported syntax error

const List = ({contents}) => {
  return (
    contents.map((content) => 
      <Item content={content}/>
    )
  )
}

export default List;
```

Comment: What about something like `export const someOutput = injectIntl(Item);`?

Comment: Thx, I found this is also working: 
`export const Item = injectIntl(({props, intl}) => {...})` 

Could you provide the reasons in-depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine:

```
export const Item = injectIntl(
 (props) => {...} 
)
```

Just don't forget the the brackets, i.e. const Item = injectIntl(**arrow function**)

Also use rest to get all existing parameters. And remove spaces from your id, otherwise querySelector will not work. In below case id is also used as a displayed label in the cell:

```js
export const TableCellId = injectIntl((props) => {
  const { id, intl, ...rest } = props
  return (
    <TableCell id={removeSpaces(id)} {...rest}>
      {mytanslation(intl, id)}
    </TableCell>
  )
})
```